# Closest Keccak256 hashes by Hamming distance?

Tags: cryptanalysis, keccak, hamming

What are the two "closest" known Keccak256 (not SHA-3 256) hashes in terms of the Hamming distance between the pair of hashes?

EDIT: This was marked as opinion based, so to clarify, when I asked this question, I was hoping that people responding would provide two hashes that had a close Hamming distance, as well as the data hashed to generate those hashes. I hope that removes any ambiguity that could result in this being seen as opinion-based.

Comment: XOR distance? That's known as Hamming distance! I don't know all calculated keccak256 hashes - nobody does. The output of a hash is randomized, so even if there was a search I don't know how it would apply to anything. Do note that the birthday *thingy* applies though and that the position of the bits doesn't matter, so finding many identical / non-identical bits will be easier than finding e.g. a hash that starts with a fixed prefix of a certain length.

Comment: Thanks for telling me what the correct term was! I know that no one knows all hashes, I guess I was just looking in terms of a "record" sense; two closest ones known to anyone. I'm trying to make an implementation of Kademlia based off of keccak256 instead of SHA1, so I was curious about minimal Hamming Distances.

Comment: Have you seen [this page about the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Generally the output of (symmetric) hash functions should be indistinguishable from random. The hash would be terribly broken if this isn't the case. With your comment I really have two questions: why not SHA-3 and why are you afraid that the Hamming distance is of influence on your protocol? Are you afraid of collisions of a downsized hash output?

Comment: I'm not afraid of any issues with the Hamming Distance, and I avoided SHA-3 simply because I'm building a cryptocurrency based off of Ethereum, which uses Keccak. I'm asking this question solely based off of curiosity; I'm trying to sort nodes into k-buckets as per Kademlia, and I was wondering about the likelihood of any nodes getting into one of the low-distance k-buckets.

Comment: Does [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8305/1172) and answers possibly answer your question? Searching is easier if you know the terms :)

Comment: I'm not so much asking for the chance of finding a small Hamming distance as I am asking for any known examples; hence the more curiosity-oriented question. If that's not appropriate for this site, then my apologies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76575/discussion-between-maarten-bodewes-and-lev-knoblock).